# AES Padding issue Android

Tags: android, encryption, padding

When I run the following code in Java the output is a multiple of 128 bits (16 bytes).

The exact same code in Android is no longer a multiple of 16 bytes suggesting that the padding has failed.

Any ideas?

```
//Compress, Encrypt, Decrypt, Decompress variables 
public final static String Secretkey = "###hidden######";
public final static String VectorInitializationKey = "###hidden###";
public final static String transformation = "AES/CFB8/PKCS5Padding";  

public static byte[] encryptandCompress(byte[] input)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream ms = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gos = null; // Added
    CipherOutputStream cos= null; // Added

    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Secretkey.getBytes(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher;

    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(VectorInitializationKey.getBytes());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        cos = new CipherOutputStream(ms, cipher ); 
        gos= new GZIPOutputStream (cos);
        gos.write(input);
        gos.close(); // Must be called before we return bytes from ms
        cos.close();
        byte[] toReturn = ms.toByteArray();  
        Log.d("FileWriter", "Encrypted and compressed " + input.length + " bytes to " + toReturn.length + " bytes");
        Log.d("FileWriter", "Encrypted and compressed " + toReturn.length/16.0 + " blocks written");

        return toReturn;        

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("FileWriter", "Compression failed: " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }

    finally 
    {
        try 
        {
            if (gos != null) 
            {
                gos.close();
            }
            if (cos != null) 
            {
                cos.close();
            }
            if (ms != null) 
            {
                ms.close();
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is in your way of obtaining the `skeySpec`, i think. You are not specifying the key size, and i think JavaSE's AES was by default capped to 128bit while Android has 256bit out-of-the-box. BTW, deriving a key directly from the psw is not secure. If I were you, I'd use `PBEKeySpec` with a salt.

Comment: I tried changing SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Secretkey.getBytes(), "AES"); to SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Secretkey.getBytes(), 0,16,"AES"); but it made no difference.  I need to decode in C# so would prefer not to use PBE.  What makes deriving a key directly from a psw insecure?

Comment: I notice that changing the transform from AES/CFB8/PKCS5Padding to AES/CFB/PKCS5Padding in Android gives the correct output length (it is in multiples of 16 bytes)

Comment: About the security of using a password as a key, yep it is not secure at all. Unless you are coding a hello world, never do that. Read more here: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/2213/5880

Comment: 1-`SecretKeySpec` constructors do not check if the byte[] used as key material has the correct length for the algorithm. In your case, both constructors have the same effect since your byte array length was already 16.

Comment: 2-About the mode, passing CFB8 requests to encrypt data in blocks of 8 bits. Read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#Cipher%28javax.crypto.CipherSpi,%20java.security.Provider,%20java.lang.String%29) the docs.

Comment: As a final note, be aware that JavaSE uses Sun JCE as cryptographic provider while Android uses Bouncycastle. As for AES-128, you shouldn't have any problem. However, AES-192 and AES-256 are not available in JavaSE by default due to US laws, so you need to install an [extension for unlimited strength](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html)